# Fraction class cannot be applied to given types?

Tags: java, windows

code throws the following error: method greatestCommonDivisor in class Fraction cannot be applied to given types;
and then follows with

> required: int,int found: no arguments reason: actual and formal
>   argument lists differ in length

I am not so sure why the error is there, I tried changing a few things with no luck

```
class Fraction{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction(int _num1, int _num2){
        numerator = _num1;
        denominator = _num2;
    }

    public int greatestCommonDivisor(int num1, int num2){
        int greatestCommon = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i <= num1 && i <= num2; i++){
            if(num1 % i == 0 && num2 % i == 0)
            greatestCommon = i;}
            return greatestCommon;
        }
}

public class testing2
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num11 = in.nextInt();
        int num22 = in.nextInt();

        Fraction gcd = new Fraction(num11, num22);
        System.out.println(gcd.greatestCommonDivisor());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear, `greatestCommonDivisor` expects two `int` parameters, you are sending none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason in quite simple:

you have to call the method like this

```
System.out.println(gcd.greatestCommonDivisor(num11, num22));
```

why?

because your method is defined as

```
int greatestCommonDivisor(int num1, int num2)
```

so,just pass the parameters you read using the scanner and you are done! :)

Comment: Then what is the benefit of providing these numbers in the `Fraction` constructor?

Comment: i agree, there is no benefit, and to be honest, that method should be static too... but the guy is learning... lets just dont break a storm on him...

Comment: Yes, that's true. He can follow both approaches. Either call the method with 2 arguments or modify the method to use the member variables that were initialized in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the `greatestCommonDivisor()` method should look like this:

```
public int greatestCommonDivisor() {
    int greatestCommon = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numerator && i <= denominator; i++) {
        if (numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0)
            greatestCommon = i;
    }
    return greatestCommon;
}
```

You are not using the member variables of `Fraction` class (provided in the constructor) here. And I would suggest renaming the `numerator` and `denominator` variable names to more accurate names like: `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` etc.